# You do not have access to library [xyz], used by your script, or it has been deleted

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries

This was very likely a Google server error.  Here are some details and the solution.

This started at 8:55pm EDT (GMT -4) Friday, October 27 and continued for almost 3 days when I stopped waiting for it to fix itself like the last problem I commented on a few weeks ago.

Nothing had changed in 17 days such that I should lose access.  The script was most certainly still there.  Everything involved was owned by "me."

What may have triggered the problem is that I set one of my libraries--not even the one that "broke"--from developer mode to fixed version mode.  At that moment, Google lost data.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63907324

Answer (score 1):

I changed two things that collectively made it work, so I don't know which was necessary, but I'll make an educated guess.

I had a base or calling script and a target or called script / library.  The called library is the one that got "lost."  However, the more important change was that I created the base from scratch with script.google.com, copied the code from the old script, and re-added the libraries.  Copying the base did not solve the problem because the library references come with the copy.

I also copied the target script wholly (rather than copying the code to a blank script).  This meant it had a new project ID.

Don't forget to re-run the scripts because you will need to re-add permissions.

---

I added the solution to the original post, but I'm posting this to formally show the question as answered.  (I'll try to remember to post the answer in the answer next time.)